# Define the term: brick

Tags: unbricking

I often see a lot of articles that say that rooting can brick your phone and render it useless like a brick, hence the name brick. But anyone who's ever fiddled around in rooting phones and installing ROMS surely knows that if you fail a ROM installation or root, the device can easily be saved by flashing a clean ROM. So what do all those articles mean by 'bricking'? Is there a way to brick a phone to the point that it doesn't even boot to the bootloader and let you install a custom recovery?

Comment: Did you read the answers here: [What does it mean to "brick" your phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29741) and here: [Why is bricking possible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/31893)

Comment: Making the phone irresponsive permanently.